# Python-сортировка DataFrame по time

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, matplotlib, dataframe

Есть БД, в которую парсятся комменты(еонкретно из нее нас интересуют столбцы comments и ttime- соответсвенно текст комментария и время его добавления). Из нее все данные загоняю в DataFrame.  Задача в следующем: построить график зависимости
кол-во комментариев/промежуток времени. Не могу понять, как подсчитывать кол-во комментариев за промежуток.. Как вообще работать с time в DataFrame?

Пример данных:

```
0  14:24:00
1  14:24:00
2  14:25:00
3  14:25:00
4  14:26:00
5  14:26:00
6  14:26:00
7  14:27:00
8  14:28:00
9  14:28:00
10 14:29:00
```

Comment: Приведите небольшой пример данных и то что вы ожидаете получить на выходе. Как вы понимаете «промежуток времени»?

Comment: данные: столбец time hours:minutes:seconds
          0     14:24:00
1     14:24:00
2     14:25:00
3     14:25:00
4     14:26:00
5     14:26:00
6     14:26:00
7     14:27:00
8     14:28:00
9     14:28:00
10    14:29:00
comments- просто текстовые данные....
 хотя, по сути, может быть он и не нужен нам??

ведь нужно только посчитать, сколько строк из столбца time войдут в каждый из заданных промежутков времени.Вопрос, как определить эти промежутки

Comment: а еще , исключительно для "попробовать" построил график, используя на оси X -time,а на Y-comments, получил ошибку: Empty 'DataFrame': no numeric data to plot

если наоборот, то вместо time в формате hh:mm:ss выдает, судя по всему, результат деления

Comment: Вс что относится к вопросу лучше указывать в самом вопросе (конпка "править" для редактирования). Вы не указали по каким интервалам времени вы хотите группировать данные - по минутам, часам, дням, как-то иначе?

Comment: по минутам, по полчаса

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Пример:

исходный DataFrame:

```
In [86]: df
Out[86]:
        time
0   14:24:00
1   14:24:00
2   14:25:00
3   14:25:00
4   14:26:00
5   14:26:00
6   14:26:00
7   14:27:00
8   14:28:00
9   14:28:00
10  14:29:00
```

Для нормальной отрисовки нам понадобится тип данных `datetime`:

```
df['time'] = pd.to_datetime('1970-01-01') + pd.to_timedelta(df['time'])
```

получилось:

```
In [22]: df
Out[22]:
                  time
0  1970-01-01 14:24:00
1  1970-01-01 14:24:00
2  1970-01-01 14:25:00
3  1970-01-01 14:25:00
4  1970-01-01 14:26:00
5  1970-01-01 14:26:00
6  1970-01-01 14:26:00
7  1970-01-01 14:27:00
8  1970-01-01 14:28:00
9  1970-01-01 14:28:00
10 1970-01-01 14:29:00
```

импорт модулей:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib
import matplotlib.dates as mdates
matplotlib.style.use('ggplot')
```

группировка и подсчет для графика (`1T` - одна минута, здесь можно указать [любой интервал](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/timeseries.html#offset-aliases)):

```
In [25]: res = df.assign(count=1).set_index('time').resample('1T').count()

In [26]: res
Out[26]:
                     count
time
1970-01-01 14:24:00      2
1970-01-01 14:25:00      2
1970-01-01 14:26:00      3
1970-01-01 14:27:00      1
1970-01-01 14:28:00      2
1970-01-01 14:29:00      1
```

график:

```
fig, ax = plt.subplots()
ax.plot(res.index, res['count'])
ax.set_xticks(res.index)
ax.xaxis.set_major_formatter(mdates.DateFormatter("%H:%M"))
```

Результат:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

PS в вашем случае `.assign(x=1)` можно не использовать т.к. у вас наверняка есть еще хотя бы один столбец кроме времени...

> а можно matplotlib явно задать промежутки?

можно:

```
fig, ax = plt.subplots()
ax.plot(res.index, res['count'])
ax.set_xticks(res.index)
ax.xaxis.set_major_locator(mdates.MinuteLocator(interval=2))  # <--- NOTE!
ax.xaxis.set_major_formatter(mdates.DateFormatter("%H:%M"))
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Поясните, пожалуйста, почему у вас получилась отсчека 50 сек? у меня совсем по-другому\
причем, почему-то неравномерными промежутками

Comment: @lynx, если вы про ось `X` - это matplotlib сам "оптимизирует" и выбирает значения временной шкалы...

Comment: спасибо,вот теперь я понимаю, что мне нужно))
исходя из задачи, нужно чтобы в каждом промежутке,с , например, 14:24:00 до 14:34:00, подсчитывалось кол-во вхождений данных из 'time' и это кол-отображалось по оси y. соответственно, на оси х- отсечки по 10 минут, например, т.е 14:24:00 14:34:00 14:44:00

Comment: а можно matplotlib явно задать промежутки?

Comment: не понял только одного, что такое mdates?

Comment: @lynx, я добавил в ответ: `import matplotlib.dates as mdates`

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/73575/discussion-between-lynx-and-maxu).

Answer (score 1):

К коду в ответе выше неплохо бы еще добавить такую строчку, чтобы более удобно выводились даты в подписях:

```
fig.autofmt_xdate()
```

тогда будет вот так удобно:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: хорошее дополнение! Я только сейчас увидел ваш ответ...